# Converting canvas to .EPS format

Tags: html5-canvas

```
var oCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var oImgBMP = Canvas2Image.saveAsEPS(oCanvas, true);
```

I tried above function to convert it into EPS but this is not working there is any easy method to save canvas into EPS. or any other method  mean pdf to EPS ...Thanks for any help

Comment: if you are using this library "Canvas2Image" then i think it does not have any method like "saveAsEps".
Check it first.

Answer (score 2):

There is no native support for getting canvas in .EPS format.

The .toDataURL will get the canvas in either PNG or JPG format, but not EPS.

```
canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");

canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

To get to EPS, you will have to send the .png or .jpg to your server (php/iis) for conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ImageMagick in WebAssembly](https://github.com/dlemstra/magick-wasm) to do it in the browser:

```js
async function canvasToEps(canvas) {
  const pngBlob = await new Promise(
    (res) => canvas.toBlob(res, 'image/png')
  );
  const imageMagick = await import('@imagemagick/magick-wasm');   
  const imageBuffer = await pngBlob.arrayBuffer();
  const imgData = new Uint8Array(imageBuffer)
  
  await imageMagick.initializeImageMagick();

  return new Promise((res) => {
    imageMagick.ImageMagick.read(imgData, (image) => {
      image.format = imageMagick.MagickFormat.Eps;
      image.write((epsImg) => res(new Blob([epsImg])));
    });
  });
}
```

`canvasToEps` returns a `blob` with the `eps` format. Internally is doing these conversions:

canvas **->** png blob **->** png array buffer **->** png Uint8Array **->** eps Uint8Array **->** blob eps

And to download the `.eps` you can use a function like this one:

```js
export function downloadFromBlob(blob, pathname) {
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', url);
  link.setAttribute('download', pathname);
  link.click();
  link.remove();
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this https://github.com/joshua-gould/canvas2pdf

> Canvas2PDF exports your HTML canvas as PDF using JavaScript. Note that this library generates actual PDF drawing calls to create a PDF with vector graphics, unlike some alternate libraries which rasterize your canvas and place it as an image in your PDF.